# How to correctly use SortedSets by key in Python sortedcontainers

Tags: python, list, sorting, ordereddictionary, sortedcontainers

**SortedListWithKey** can sort a list using a lambda function:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedListWithKey

SortedListWithKey([[4, 'last'], [1, 'first']], key=lambda x: x[0])
# Result: SortedListWithKey([[1, 'first'], [4, 'last']], key=<function <lambda> at 0x107f5d730>)
```

But let's say I need to use **set()** to have only unique values, the [documentation](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedset.html) says that it also accepts a **key=** param for sorting by a custom function, but I cannot get it to work:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedSet

SortedSet([[4, 'last'], [1, 'first']], key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Will throw the following exception:

```
values = set(chain(*iterables))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sorted set requires elements be hashable. Your elements are lists which don't support hashing. Change the elements to tuples and it will work:

```
>>> from sortedcontainers import SortedSet
>>> ss = SortedSet([(4, 'last'), (1, 'first')], key=lambda value: value[0])
>>> ss
SortedSet([(1, 'first'), (4, 'last')], key=<function <lambda> at 0x10fff4848>)
```

This sorted set will order elements by the first index in the pair. The benefit of tuples is that they're hashable, the drawback is they're immutable.

Consider using a [sortedcontainers.SortedDict](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html) instead:

```
>>> sd = SortedDict({4: 'last', 1: 'first'})
>>> sd
SortedDict({1: 'first', 4: 'last'})
>>> sd[2] = 'second'
>>> sd.pop(4)
'last'
```

The sorted dict will keep keys in sorted order and let you update the values to anything you like.

Comment: hi Grant, I find that SortedSet([(1, 'last'), (1, 'first')], key=lambda value: value[0]) returns a set with both elements, even though there is a key collision. It seems that SortedSet.add() function does not check for key collision with the provided key function either. Is that an intended feature or can it be improved? This is stopping me from using SortedSet for a custom class object with a key field. Maybe I can move the key out of the class and use it as a key for SortedDict, but that sounds like a workaround. Wanted to check with you on this.

Comment: The key is just for sort order. The set applies to all elements. Sounds like you want a sorted dictionary instead.

Comment: I'd expect any set, including `SortedSet`, to enforce uniqueness based on a key. Just found that I should implement `__eq__` and `__hash__` in my custom class to make the built-in `set`, and therefore `SortedSet`, to enforce uniqueness.

Comment: The key parameter is based on sorted()’s. The set() type has no such parameter.